# Need help to get username and password from a server

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to retrieve a username and a password from a server, but I'm stuck with a problem. I've to take the parameters and use them to verify if the the input (username/password) is correct and exists in the server.
However, I don't know how to do this. I've tried to declare the variables as null, but the problem would be that it'll check if user = null with pass = null exists in the server, which it doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Skiftkode</title></head>
    <h1>Log ind</h1>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Skiftkode.jsp">
            Brugernavn (studienummer): <input type="text" name="brugernavn"> <br>
            Adgangskode: <input type="password" name="adgangskode"> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log ind">
        </form>
        <%
                QName qname = new QName("http://soap.transport.brugerautorisation/", "BrugeradminImplService");
                URL url = new URL("http://javabog.dk:9901/brugeradmin?wsdl");

                Service service = Service.create(url, qname); //I'm connecting to the server here, and it connects
                Brugeradmin ba = service.getPort(Brugeradmin.class);

                Bruger b = ba.hentBruger(String brugernavn, String kode); //Here, I'm trying to retrieve an account. Now it says 

                String bn, ak;

                bn = request.getParameter("brugernavn");
                ak = request.getParameter("adgangskode");
                if (user.equals(bn) && password.equals(ak)) { //here I'm checking whether it exists or not
                    // sæt attributten "logget ind" i sessionen
                    session.setAttribute("logget ind", "ja");
                    out.println("Du er logget korrekt ind.<br>");
                } else {
                    session.removeAttribute("logget ind");
                    out.println("Fejl");
                }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the interface with the method:

```
@WebService
public interface Brugeradmin
{

    @WebMethod Bruger hentBruger(String brugernavn, String adgangskode);  

    @WebMethod Bruger ændrAdgangskode(String brugernavn, String adgangskode, String nyAdgangskode);

    @WebMethod void sendEmail(String brugernavn, String adgangskode, String emne, String tekst);

    @WebMethod void sendGlemtAdgangskodeEmail(String brugernavn, String følgetekst);

    @WebMethod void setEkstraFelt(String brugernavn, String adgangskode, String feltnavn, Object værdi);

    @WebMethod Object getEkstraFelt(String brugernavn, String adgangskode, String feltnavn);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send password back to the client?

Comment: I want to check if the input (username/password) exists in the server. For instance let's say here on Stackoverflow. You've to write your username/email and password, then the server will check if the account exists. In my case, if the account exists, it has to print `out.println("Du er logget korrekt ind.<br>")`

Comment: Where do you want to authenticate it? database?

Comment: I want to compare the input (username/password) with the accounts in the server

Comment: Yes, I want to send back the username/password to the client

Comment: I don't get this. The client should send the username and password to the server, and the server should validate it. The client doesn't need to be sent the password.

Comment: Yes exactly. So if the username/password are correct then it has to print a string

Comment: So why does your title read 'need help to get a username and password from a server'?

Comment: Because I need to check whether the username/password exists in the server or not

Comment: Sigh. You need to check that *at the server.* You don't need to return the password to the client. The client already knows his own password, and he certainly doesn't need to be told anybody else's. Both your title and the first paragraph of your question are about something you don't need to do at all.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the API should be used as follows:

```
        if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) { // Form data sent
            String bn = request.getParameter("brugernavn");
            String ak = request.getParameter("adgangskode");
            Bruger b = ba.hentBruger(bn, ak);
            if (b != null && b. ...) {
                ...
```

Comment: Can't I just write until  `Bruger b = ba.hentBruger(bn, ak); out.println("Success")` ?

Comment: Try it - I do not know. There should be some failure notification. Good luck.